# Connecting Cisco Ctalyst 3850 Fibre switch to Cisco Catalyst 2960

Tags: cisco

I am working on a network that has fibre connection terminated to the 3850 fibre switch. I want to connect 2960 to this 3850 switch. I want to use the SFP port to link them up together. Please how do i go about it.

Thank you

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Any time I have have configured a link such as this in smaller networks using these two pieces of equipment I trunk the link that is the fiber link containing the SFP on both ends, define encapsulation and native vlans and then define allowed vlans on the trunk. I know iit isnt always a standard, it depends on what IOS version and platform etc...but I also define no negotiate on the trunk port to avoid encapsulation issues.

This shouldnt be a problem with a 2960 though I believe they only are capable of dot1Q.

Best,